VSCode does not debug code when the start address is not 0x8000000 on an STM32
Im trying to debug STM32 code using VSCode and OpenOCD. If the start address of the code is 0x0800000 it works fine, but when I move it to account for my bootloader, vscode will not locate the start of the code after the debug button is pressed. Oddly, the Eclipse based IDE works perfectly. I looked at the terminal output of both Eclispe and VSCode when debugging starts and GDB and OpenOCD output looks identical. Here is my launch.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "executable": "app.elf",
            "name": "OPENOCD",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "runToEntryPoint": "main",
            "serverpath":"/Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.openocd.macos64_2.3.200.202312181736/tools/bin/openocd",
            "servertype": "openocd",
            "searchDir": [
                "/Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.debug.openocd_2.2.0.202401261111/resources/openocd/st_scripts"
            ],
            "serverArgs": [
                "-c", "gdb_port 50000",
                "-c", "gdb_report_data_abort enable" ,
                "-c", "tcl_port 50001",
                "-c", "telnet_port 50002"
            ],
            "device": "STM32L452xx",
            "interface": "swd",
            "showDevDebugOutput": "parsed",
            "configFiles": [
                app.cfg",
            ],
            "svdFile": "${workspaceFolder}/STM32L4X2.svd"
        }
    ]
}


